# how can i slove this opencv python issue on contures?

Tags: python, opencv

```
contours = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cnts = contours[0]
screenCnt = 0

for contour in contours:
    # get rectangle bounding contour
    [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
 
##### code added..for thresholding
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then
    # we can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
```

---

```
error  traceback (most recent call last)
/home/gpanchada/Desktop/new/try.ipynb Cell 5 in <cell line: 6>()
      4 screenCnt = 0
      6 for contour in contours:
      7     # get rectangle bounding contour
----> 8     [x,y,w,h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
      9     # [x,y,w,h] = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
     10 
     11 
   (...)
     14 
     15 ##### code added..for thresholding
     16 for c in cnts:
     17     # approximate the contour

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'boundingRect'
Overload resolution failed:
- array is not a numerical tuple
- Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'
```

Comment: Add umat at the end. cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]

Comment: nooo, UMat doesn't help. do not misunderstand the error message -- you haven't debugged your code. do that and you *should* notice that you're confusing yourself with your variable names. you have `contours`, `cnts`, `contour`, ... you should call `(contours, hierarchy) = cv.findContours...` instead -- **voting to close because the question stems from a typo** please review [ask] and [mre]